# Is it possible to override MultipartFormDataStreamProvider so that uploads can be encrypted before saving to the file system?

Tags: encryption, asp.net-web-api

I Need to upload file in my project. I am using asp.net webapi for that purpose. I want to encrypt the uploads before it gets save to filesystem. Same way I want to decrypt it before sending it back to the client.
I tried to get stream in the GetStream method of MultipartFormDataStreamProvider but it is not working.
 public override Stream GetStream(HttpContent parent, HttpContentHeaders headers)
        {
            var stream = base.GetStream(parent, headers);
            Rijndael myRijndael = Rijndael.Create();
            Stream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream();
            // Create a encryptor to perform the stream transform.
            ICryptoTransform encryptor = myRijndael.CreateEncryptor(myRijndael.Key, myRijndael.IV);
            CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);

```
        ContentDispositionHeaderValue contentDisposition = headers.ContentDisposition;
        if (contentDisposition != null)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(contentDisposition.FileName))
            {
                try
                {
                    byte[] bytearrayinput = new byte[stream.Length - 1];
                  csEncrypt.Write(bytearrayinput, 0, bytearrayinput.Length);
                    encrypted = msEncrypt;
                    msEncrypt.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    return msEncrypt;
                }
                catch (Exception)

                    throw;
                }
                finally
                {
                    myRijndael.Dispose();
                    msEncrypt.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        return new MemoryStream();
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks
Karuna

Comment: "not working" isn't a helpful diagnostic phrase, especially when you expect us to remotely debug the code that you've not shown us.

Comment: Can you share what you have tried?

Comment: Sorry guys. I have overriden the GetStream method in MultipartformDataStreamProvider as below:

Comment: I have modified my original post since I have not able to add more comments here.